# Facebook SDK API - using markdown in page post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to post a status update to a page's wall using Markdown in the message text. Using the below API call and passing in the `formatting` parameter, I get an error - `This app does not have permission to manage this Workplace account.`

```
FB.api('/123456/feed', 'post', {formatting : 'MARKDOWN', message : '**Test Message**', access_token : '123456789'}, function(response) {
            if (!response || response.error) {
              console.log(response);
            } else {
              console.log(response);
            }
          });
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/workplace/integrations/custom-integrations/reference/post

Nothing with my app requires a Facebook Workplace account. Is there anyway to use markdown to post to a page's wall?

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: Did you find a solution?